# Simple way to capture screenshot in windows os? c++

Tags: c++, windows, screenshot, capture

What is the most simple way to capture a screenshot and save it somewhere using c++?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/FAQ)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help:
[How can I take a screenshot in a windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291167/how-to-make-screen-screenshot-with-win32-in-c)
or http://planetsourcecode.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=10754&lngWId=3