# How to capture desktop screen of computer host where it's running on using node.js

Tags: node.js, screenshot, capture, screen-capture

Is there such a way to capture desktop with node.js not a browser tab?

I have searched a lot but I didn't find any.

What I want is to use node.js to build desktop application.

Comment: I know that node specialized for web but also it could be used to build console applications

Comment: Yes but console applications have nothing to with the GUI, you wont be able to create proper GUI desktop applications with a serviceside programming language.

Comment: I'm not looking for a GUI,Desktop applications can have a GUI or can't, so console is enough

Comment: If you're on Windows, you could use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69063244/2441655

Answer (score 8):

You can use

http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

and

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrot

to make screenshot of screen of current user running nodejs application. 
Something like this (it is complete expressJS example):

```
var express = require('express'),
  childProcess = require('child_process'),
  app = express();

app.get('/screenshot.png', function(request,response){
  childProcess.exec('scrot screenshot.png', function(err){
    if(err1) {
      response.send(503,'Error creating image!');
    } else {
       response.sendfile('screenshot.png')
    }
  });
});
app.listen(3000);
```

But this is quite slow approach.

Comment: Please show how to do real-time fast approach and make it available for VLC or Google chrome to re-capture.

Comment: it can be quite untrivial - it will require ffmpeg for generating real time feed and icecast server for broadcasting - better to ask it in separate question

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just call an external program?

For example, you could call import:

```
$ import -window root screenshot.png
```

The code:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('import -window root screenshot.png', function (error, stdout, stderr){
    // now you have the screenshot
});
```

Comment: how to save screenshot.png

Comment: Do you use linux? Do you have imagemagick installed? If not, change "import" by your favourite program to take screenshots.

Comment: You can install imagemagick for windows. http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows Then you can use the import command. Maybe the command parameters are different so read the documentation.

Comment: I have monitor 1, monitor 2 connected. when i use to take screenshot how can i tell take screenshot of monitor 1 and 2 or take from monitor 2 only or monitor 1 only?

Answer (score 2):

Full Resolution

```
var screenshot = require('desktop-screenshot');

screenshot("screenshot.png", function(error, complete) {
    if(error)
        console.log("Screenshot failed", error);
    else
        console.log("Screenshot succeeded");
});
```

Resize to 400px wide, maintain aspect ratio

```
var screenshot = require('desktop-screenshot');

screenshot("screenshot.png", {width: 400}, function(error, complete) {
    if(error)
        console.log("Screenshot failed", error);
    else
        console.log("Screenshot succeeded");
});
```

Resize to 400x300, set JPG quality to 60%

```
var screenshot = require('desktop-screenshot');

screenshot("screenshot.jpg", {width: 400, height: 300, quality: 60}, function(error, complete) {
    if(error)
        console.log("Screenshot failed", error);
    else
        console.log("Screenshot succeeded");
});
```

Comment: how to a specify the folder I want to store the screenshot in

Answer (score 0):

For the newcomers ,

There is a npm package called desktop-screenshot for exactly the same purpose.

[Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/desktop-screenshot) it is

You can find an addon where the screenshot is taken and saved to any user defined path.User can also specify a time interval for the screenshot capture. [Here](https://github.com/jayadevkv/screen-capture)

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you should rephrase your question as follow:

> How to capture desktop screen of computer host where it's running on http client's request and send back the image as response

If that's what you actually mean, you can [write your own add-on module](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) using native compiler. For reference, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291167/how-to-make-screen-screenshot-with-win32-in-c)).