# Take screenshot using virtual keys using c++

Tags: c++, image, screenshot

I want to make a program which takes screenshot whenever it runs. For that, I thought of using virtual keys but i am not able to press two keys simultaneously. I am trying to do this in Microsoft windows 8.1 and trying to press <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Print Scrn</kbd> simultaneously.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make screen screenshot with win32 in c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291167/how-to-make-screen-screenshot-with-win32-in-c)

Comment: No, this is not what I want. I want to press and hold windows logo key and then press prtscn and then release those two buttons.

Comment: Your title says: `without pressing any key`.  So which is it?

Comment: I meant without pressing it physically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send multiple keys to the OS with [`keybd_event()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx).  The first time you call it you will send the windows key and tell it to stay down.  Then you will do the same with the printscreen button.  After you do that you need to call the function again to lift each key in reverse order.  You should be able to use:

```
keybd_event(VK_LWIN, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
keybd_event(VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
keybd_event(VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
keybd_event(VK_LWIN, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

Comment: `keybd_event()` is deprecated, use `SendInput()` instead.  Put your events into an `INPUT` array, and then pass the array to `SendInput()`.  The main benefit of this is that simulating the array is done atomically (ie, no other events can occur in between your events), whereas calling `keybd_event()` for each event individually is not atomic.