# How to get cursor shape?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

How can I get cursor shape when application minimized?

on hotkey I call:

```
qDebug() << "mouse (" << QCursor::pos().x() <<  "x" << QCursor::pos().y() << ")" << this->cursor().shape();
```

QCursor::pos() - is right, but cursor().shape() - always return "ArrowCursor" (even within the application).

How can I get real shape or cursor pixmap (Windows, MacOS)?

Comment: Why in the world are you interested in such a thing?

Comment: From Qt Assistant: "`QCursor::pixmap() const` Returns the cursor pixmap. This is only valid if the cursor is a pixmap cursor." Is it?

Comment: @peppe When you want a non-standard cursor based on a standard one (e.g. coloured). Or when you need a non-standard behaviour that should show a standard familiar cursor.

Comment: @ilotXXI: that doesn't sound at all about what OP is asking. OP is asking about getting the cursor shape when the cursor is currently in another application or similar, which is a very strange use case to me.

Comment: @peppe I capture screenshot and need to impose cursor on him over.

Comment: Ok, in which case I'm afraid you'll need to use platform specific code. There's no way in Qt. (However those platform specific ways should be well documented...)

Comment: @peppe mey be you have some link how to do that in win and osx?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291167/how-to-make-screen-screenshot-with-win32-in-c plus calls into [GetCursorInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648389(v=vs.85).aspx) and DrawIcon to draw it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this, at least not with Qt.

`this->cursor()` gives you a `QCursor` that was set on a certain `QWidget` using `QWidget::setCursor`. It's a simple accessor. It does not give you the current cursor being displayed (outside your program, window, not even outside the widget).