# Get All Pixels From The Screen As Array(C++, Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

If I wanted to get all the pixels from the current display and load them into a c++ array, what would be the best way to do that. I've tried getting each pixel individually but as expected, it is incredibly slow. Is there a better way to do so?

Note: I would prefer an OS-independent solution but I don't expect there to be an easy one so Windows solutions would be preferred.

Comment: That would be a **BIG** array, depending on the current screen resolution. What's your use case for this? Did you mean to interact with the GPU directly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I take a screenshot in a windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291167/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-in-a-windows-application)