# The right way to capture screenshot using Rust

Tags: winapi, rust

I have been looking for an answer to this question for several days and so on until the end, I have not completely figured it out. It is worth clarifying that I am looking for a way not just to save the screenshot as a file, but to get an array of bytes and array of bytes decoded to png/jpg or another lightweight image format.
The first way i tried was [screenshot-rs](https://crates.io/crates/screenshot-rs/0.1.5) crate, code like this:

```
let s = match get_screenshot(0) {
        Ok(it) => it,
        _ => return,
    };

    let mut buf = Vec::<u8>::new();

    let encoder = PngEncoder::new(&mut buf);
    unsafe {
        match encoder.encode(
            std::slice::from_raw_parts(s.raw_data(), s.raw_len()),
            s.width() as u32,
            s.height() as u32,
            image::ColorType::Rgba8,
        ) {
            Ok(it) => it,
            _ => return,
        };
    }
```

(I use png encoder too)

Formally, this code works but works very slowly (around ~5 sec) and producec screenshot with switched blue and red color channels.

After this i start trying to use winapi to capture screenshot, but my knowledge about winapi, hundreds of data types and what i have to do now (this doesnt work properly)

```
let x1 = GetSystemMetrics(78);
        let y1 = GetSystemMetrics(79);
        let x2 = GetSystemMetrics(76);
        let y2 = GetSystemMetrics(77);
        let w = x2 - x1;
        let h = y2 - y1;

        let hdc_screen = GetDC(ptr::null_mut());
        let hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc_screen);
        let h_bitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc_screen, w, h);
        let obj = SelectObject(hdc, h_bitmap as HGDIOBJ);
        let status = BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, w, h, hdc_screen, x1, y1, SRCCOPY);
```

Comment: *"this doesnt work properly"* - How so? What do you get? Did you read the documentation for [BitBlt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-bitblt), particularly what the formal parameters `x1` and `y1` are? Did you read the documentation for [GetSystemMetrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetrics)?

Comment: I do it like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28248531/14891298

Comment: No, you aren't.